# K8s Ingress for nodeport. Example for beginners

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Can you help me? I want to deploy Ingres for nodeport. But I can't understand if this possible?

I tried to find some information in Google but I got Ingress for load balancing or some difficult examples Ingress Ruby on rails and etc.

Comment: so, you have made a search, and were not able to find one example? I could write an answer only with like 10 links to working examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to provide the simplest example that I can think of below. I will use the `nginxdemos/hello` docker image for my example. Locally this works as this:

```
$docker run -p 80:80 -d nginxdemos/hello    
...
$curl -I http://localhost

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.13.8
Date: Tue, 08 Oct 2019 06:14:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Tue, 08 Oct 2019 06:14:51 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Cool. Here is our backend deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-backend
  namespace: java2days
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-server
          image: nginxdemos/hello
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: server-port
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 3
```

Shortly we will have 2 replicas of an nginx server. Up and running on nodes somewhere in the cloud:

```
$kubectl get pods

NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-backend-dfcdb9797-dnx7x   1/1     Running   0          21m
nginx-backend-dfcdb9797-pnrhn   1/1     Running   0          21m
```

Let's create a NodePort service now. Here is the service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: java2days
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
      name: http
  selector:
    app: nginx-server
  type: NodePort
```

Note the selector, it matches the backend service. Now it is time for the ingress controller.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: java2days
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: nginx-service
              servicePort: 80
            path: /*
```

You will have to wait for about 5-10 minutes until GCloud provisions an IP address for this Ingress. Finally it is done, something like this:

```
$kubectl get ingress

NAME            HOSTS   ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
nginx-ingress   *       x.y.z.p         80      15m
```

From my local machine now:

```
$curl -I http://x.y.z.p

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Great it is working. If you open it in the browser and refresh multiple times you will see that the server ID changes and load balancing works. Additional entry point for reading - [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress).

Do not forget to clean up the resources when you finish experimenting.

Answer (score 2):

Create deployment and service

```
kubectl create deploy test --image httpd
kubectl expose deploy test --port 80 --target-port 80
```

Check if the service is working

```
kubectl get svc
```

returns

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
test         ClusterIP   11.105.18.110   <none>        80/TCP    51s
```

Then

```
curl 11.105.18.110:80
```

returns

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

Create bare-metal ingress controller

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.0.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
```

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal

This returns

```
namespace/ingress-nginx unchanged
serviceaccount/ingress-nginx unchanged
configmap/ingress-nginx-controller configured
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission created
service/ingress-nginx-controller created
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller created
ingressclass.networking.k8s.io/nginx unchanged
validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission configured
serviceaccount/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create created
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch created
```

Create ingress rules for nginx controller

```
kubectl apply -f -<<EOF
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx  
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
EOF
```

**Annotation "kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx" is required to bind Ingress to the controller**

https://www.fairwinds.com/blog/intro-to-kubernetes-ingress-set-up-nginx-ingress-in-kubernetes-bare-metal

Get nodes ips

```
kubectl get no -o wide

NAME    STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   
master  Ready    control-plane,master   6d20h   v1.21.0   134.156.0.81   
node1   Ready    <none>                 5d      v1.21.0   134.156.0.82   
node2   Ready    <none>                 6d19h   v1.21.0   134.156.0.83   
node3   Ready    <none>                 6d19h   v1.21.0   134.156.0.84
```

Find ingress controller nodeport

```
kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx 

NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    15.234.89.16    <none>        80:31505/TCP,443:32191/TCP   21m
```

Its 31505. Access test service over ingress node port on one of your nodes, for example on node1 134.156.0.82

```
curl 134.156.0.82:31505
```

returns

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

This was tested on Google Cloud virtual machines but without GKE

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind ingress is you need to use an ingress controller, how you expose the ingress controller is completely up to you as you would use a Kubernetes services to expose it, for example, if you wanted to use ingress on a nodeport your structure would look similar to:

```
service exposing nodeport ==> ingress controller ==> web app service (via ingress) ==> web app
```

This is a general flow as it doesn't matter how you expose your ingress controller (LoadBalancer, NodePort, etc) the routing will generally be base on hostname i.e if my NodePort is exposed on 172.64.0.25:30965 then I would point my domain at that IP and the ingress routes based on the host that it gets routed with. There is a lot of documentation on this that can be found [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) (this is for the Nginx ingress controller but all ingress routing is very similar)